# TYPO3 Extension: create database view during installation

Tags: installation, typo3, typo3-extensions, database-view

In my TYPO3 extension I use a foreign table. I've created 2 views providing data of this table in the manner my extension needs.

The question is - how can these views be created at installation time?

Views defined in "**ext_tables.sql**" are ingored by installation routine.

I've tried to use file "**ext_tables_static+adt.sql**". This variant works only for `INSERT` statements.

The only thing I've got to work is variant described [here](https://aimeos.org/tips/how-to-execute-scripts-after-installing-typo3-extensions/) using **signal slot dispatcher** (sounds complicated but it is really not! Provided documentation is very good).

But I can't believe it that there is no native way (like `ext_tables.sql`) to solve such problems.

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on this issue some time ago. There was no other way to achive what you want at that time and I doubt there‘s evolved a new one in the meantime.

- I ended up using the hook you mentioned and made it read and execute all `Configuration/SQL/*.sql` from my extension.
- There is a way to modify SQL schema at runtime but it is limited to the usual `CREATE TABLE` (pseudo) statements. Use signal     `TYPO3\CMS\Install\Service\SqlExpectedSchemaService` - `tablesDefinitionIsBeingBuilt` for this. It is used in [TYPO3 core](http://api.typo3.org/typo3cms/current/html/class_t_y_p_o3_1_1_c_m_s_1_1_core_1_1_category_1_1_category_registry.html#a7625101ec47618382ebd94a99e806991) in     `TYPO3\CMS\Core\Category\CategoryRegistry::addCategoryDatabaseSchemaToTablesDefinition`
- Maybe TYPO3‘s switch to [doctrine/dbal](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/index.html) will change the situation. As you can [see](https://forger.typo3.org/doctrine), migration‘s under way…

Be aware that there‘s no way to teach install tool‘s database analyzer your views so it will keep nagging you about removing them.